# Indesign shuffling page

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have a preset layout on Indesign CC V. 9.1 with a document that has 5 chapters, A front matter, back matter, endnotes and appendices. I have the layout as a facing page--needed for odd and even formats. Everytime, I add an extra page so that way my next chapter could start on the right side(front of the book/report), the chapters after that shift the textbox frame out and shuffle their top margins. The left page goes from 1.5inch to 2inch of a margin and the right side goes from 10inch to 10.5inch and I have to move it all back.

My bleed and slugs are all the same at .125 in, Facing pages are on. I don't understand why this is happening and how can I change this so that way it doesn't shuffle?

Comment: Does your master page have different margins for the left and right? Are you certain it's the text frames moving and not just the margins changing?

Comment: @Scott, you are right the margins are off, but why would the designer, create different margins?

Comment: Because in a book the inside or gutter margin needs to be different than the page edge margin. This allows text to move slightly (called creep) when the pages are printed and bound.

Comment: So I can't really change the margins to prevent my pages from moving the margin? @Scott

Comment: Well, the easy way around this is to *always* add 2 pages, not one. That way existing items remain on the right/left as they are. Then delete any extra pages at the end. But ultimately, it always requires you to manually ensure text is properly located for the page it is on.

Answer (score 3):

Are all of you text boxes aligned to baseline grid? Maybe some are and some aren't?
**Make sure you have the same master pages for both sides of the booklet or at least to align it appropriately.**
Regarding the indesign document and the need to add pages - I'm not so sure you need all that. Think about how you are going to bind the book. If you are going to use *Stab Stitched or Side Stitched binding* you also have to make sure each chapter has a number of pages that separates itself by 4 and so on.
**In any case - try to always add the amount of pages that will leave you with every page in the same side of the paper as it was before (always add in pairs!)**