# Why does my master page move when the page shuffles left/right?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am laying out a book in Adobe InDesign.

Context: Since creating the original book document, I have changed the page size from 6x9 to 7x10. All my master pages are of the new size (7x10). (I have a feeling this relates to the problem somehow.) I have page shuffling turned on.

When a page shuffles from left to right or right to left (due to an earlier chapter changing the number of pages), the master page moves -- and is now misaligned with the page.

Before shuffle:

[image: Correct alignment]

After shuffle -- note how the master page no longer overlaps the real page correctly (which messes up a bunch of other things).

If I right click on the page and re-apply the master page, it's fixed. This is a pretty long document and I can't do that for all the pages. (I could one time -- but doing that every time a page changes is going to cause a lot of issue.)

[image: Incorrect alignment]

**Edit**

Added some more screenshots with simpler master page, where nothing is off the page. The same thing happens.

Before shuffle. Note how the master page correctly sits immediately on top of the actual page, with the correct boundaries.
[image: Before shuffle]

After shuffle. Note how the master page is now *misaligned* with the actual page. 
[image: After shuffle]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Indesign shuffling page](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/48958/indesign-shuffling-page) -- It's not the objects that move.... it's your differing margins between left and right pages. Not really sure why you have a box around the entire page edge.

Comment: The inner and outer margins are different, but they're not *that* different to cause it to move by an inch. I don't believe it is a duplicate of that question. That question seems to be describing a different issue.

Comment: I assume the "box" you are talking about is the "show master overlay" option. As you can see, the master page is no longer on top of the page. The objects are moving, but only in relation to the master page. That thicker blue box is the master page. The thinner blue box is the actual page boundaries.

Comment: Well by default Indesign wants to keep elements on the page. You've got a rule stretching across the bottom of the spread it looks like. I bet if you remove the "Z-chapter", the box, and the rule across the bottom, nothing moves except the margins.

Comment: What rule? The thing next to the page number? Yes, I do have that... not following your point. The "Z-Chapter" is the name of the master page (that's not text on the page -- that's InDesign's "Show Master Overlay" option) and the thicker blue box is the boundary of the master page. Are you saying that I should remove the master page and then it wouldn't move? I mean, yes, but... that's kind of my question. I need a master page.

Comment: My question is not "why are my objects moving with my master page?" The objects are moving with the master page. That makes perfect sense. My question is "Why isn't my master page actually on top of the page?"

Comment: Then I don't understand I guess. Master pages are *always* the bottom object in the page stack unless you [utilize Layers to move things to a different stacking order](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9344/master-page-display-on-top-in-indesign).

Comment: Of course it should be the bottom. But why isn't it *lined up* with the page? Do you see both screenshots, or is for some reason only one showing up?

Assuming you see two... Okay, see that big, thick blue box on the second screenshot? That's the border of the master page. The "Z-Chapter Start" is just the name of the master page. 

See that thin blue blue (just inside the red box)? That's the actual page. 

See how they're *not the same*? They are in the first screenshot, but not in the second. In the second one, the master page boundaries are shifted to the right. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Please re-red my second comment here. Your *extra items outside the page* cause everything to shift.

Comment: Which elements are outside the page? I added some new screenshots where, for sure, nothing is outside the page.

Comment: See my answer.. that bottom rule, under "Z-chapter", is *absolutely* off the page.

Comment: No... that's not a bottom rule. That's the page boundary that's on every document.

Comment: this would be a *lot* easier to see if you could do screenshots without the background grid.

Comment: Questions: 1. Are you using multiple page sizes in your document? If yes, what are they? 2. Are you utilizing the InDesign "Book" feature for your chapters, or are all chapters in one InDesign document?

Comment: 1. No, all pages should be the same size. 2. Yes, I'm using the Book feature.

Comment: Old question, I know, but have you made sure to update all your existing document pages to 7x10, as well as changing your master pages? ‘Custom page sizes’ can be some of the most infuriatingly stubborn things to change in InDesign. Though even with that, I have no idea how the master can possibly get misaligned with the page. They’re supposed to be the same thing as far as boundaries are concerned.

Answer (score 1):

You're items are shifting due to the text and rule you have resting on and *off* the page.

[image]

Note the rule which is off the page bottom and extends to some bleed margin on the right (out of view). If this is a *text frame* with a paragraph rule applied, and the text *is* resting *on the page*, InDesign wants to keep the text on the page.

So when you shuffle pages....

[image]

That text frame gets moved to align the rule with the bleed on the *left* side.

InDesign is maintaining placement based relative to the page bleeds.

In your **second** set of samples the *exact same issue* exists. You've got objects off the page extending to bleeds. InDesign is merely trying to keep things on the page.

Note that the relative placement of *everything* else on the page is in alignment with each other. It is this bottom rule which is being adjusted when you shuffle pages, and causing everything else to try and maintain the same relative position to it.

I suspect that bottom rule extends to the right in your first example the exact same distance items are moving to the right when you shuffle pages.

Comment: What rule are you referring to? I really don't understand. That black line under Z-Chapter Start? The red line? The thick blue box? None of those are rules. The only rule I have is the black line above "Cracking the Coding Interview", which is well within the page boundary... isn't it?

Comment: The black line. Note how **it** is the item with a changing position seen by the left alignment with "Z-Chapter". I thought it was just the bottom of the page, but it's appearing as part of your selection as well.

Comment: If that's not the page boundary, then I have absolutely no idea how to remove it. Because it's not on my master page and even a brand new document has that.

Comment: It's not appearing as part of a selection, as far I know. It's the page boundary. When you click "Show Master Overlay", it shows the location of the master page and also the underlying document.

Comment: Perhaps the "show master overlay" option is confusing you? Here are some more images: [link](http://imgur.com/bh1bSLd,YVht0ea,lTRXfN8,UBE93Xg). The first image is without the "show master overlay" option on, and before shuffling. The second image is a totally blank document - note the black border is still there. The third image is after page shuffle, WITH "show master overlay" turn on. The fourth image is the exact same, but without that turn on.

Comment: Well now *I'm* confused. :) Perhaps bad/corrupt document?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe. InDesign is super buggy, so... hard to say. I can't really start over though because it would mess up a ton of links.

Comment: I don't have an answer, because frankly ever since...Pagemaker (?), I never insert or delete except in pairs (spreads) and so I never had this problem. **I do note however** that the center gadget of the misaligned box after shuffle is at 3.5 inches. The same as before the odd/even shuffle.

Comment: Usually when I see shifting it's because some element on a left page overlaps the right page (or vice versa). Even a 1pixel overlap can create item movement.

Answer (score 0):

( Ok, I "lied" in the comments on Scott's thread. I will answer.)

In your pre- and post-shuffle images, the center gadget is at the 3.5 inch mark.

Try changing the "zero point" of the document ruler to "top left" before shuffling.

> Choose Edit > Preferences > Units & Increments (Windows) or InDesign > Preferences > Units & Increments (Mac OS).

Reference: [Adobe Help Doc](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/rulers-measurement-units.html)

Comment: Rulers *appear* to be set at 0 for the gutter, which is normal.

Comment: Rulers appear to be at 0, 0. When I go to Preferences > Units and Increments, the origin is set to Page (which I think is correct?).

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem. Be sure the **margins** on your master pages are set to your desired specs, and that your "Primary Text Frames" (checked when creating the document) are set in those margins. In my case, I needed my outer margins to be wider than my inner to allow for notes and graphics in the outer margins. Simply setting the master text frames to my desired dimensions would not make them appear correctly on the pages as I added/deleted pages (they'd appear in the wrong places on all subsequent pages). Only when the master page MARGINS were set correctly (the magenta box in the image below) did my document flow correctly when pages were inserted/deleted mid-document.

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a different issue from the one Gayle is asking about here. It sounds like in your case, the text frames were misaligned on the pages, whereas in Gayle’s case, it’s the _master pages_ themselves that were misaligned with the document pages.